# barplot not working

Tags: r

```
bars <- list(v=1:10, a=2:11)
barplot(bars, col=c("green", "black"))
```

I can't understand why this code doesn't work, I get this error:

```
Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

**UPDATE:**
I need a grouped barplot, with 10 groups and two bars in each group

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably you want this:

```
bars <- cbind(1:10, 2:11)
barplot(bars, beside = TRUE, col = c("green", "black"))
```

The error appeared because `bars` is a list and height has to be either a vector or matrix of values describing the bars.

*Edit*:

In order to get 10 groups of 2 bars you need to transpose the `bars` matrix

```
barplot(t(bars), beside = TRUE, col = c("green", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: I need a grouped barplot, with 10 groups and two bars in each group