# R Error when using beside=TRUE parameter

Tags: r

I am plotting a graph with `barplot()` and any attempts to use the `beside=TRUE` parameter seem to return the error of `Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

The following is the code for the graph:

```
combi <- as.matrix(combine)

barplot(combi, main="Top 5 hospitals in California", 
ylab="Mortality/Admission Rates", col = heat.colors(5), las=1)
```

The output of the graph is that the bars are stacked on each other instead of being beside each other.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Strange, this error should only be occurring if `combi` is not a matrix, q.v. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909665/barplot-not-working

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have attempted to change the combi using the t() but it is not working whenever i add the beside=TRUE parameter

Comment: Can you show us your dataset `combine`?

Comment: @J_F   Please check the edited post

Comment: When `combine` is a data.frame, your issue is not reproducible. I have tested it with your data. can you check with `is(combine)` and  `is(combi)`?

Comment: @J_F is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Check the commands from my comment before.

Comment: @J_F could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not reproducible, when `combine`is a data.frame:

```
combine <- data.frame(
  HeartAttack = c(13.4,12.3,16,13,15.2),
  HeartFailure = c(11.1,7.3,10.7,8.9,10.8),
  Pneumonia = c(11.8,6.8,10,9.9,9.5),
  HeartAttack2 = c(18.3,19.3,21.8,21.6,17.3),
  HeartFailure2 = c(24,23.3,24.2,23.8,24.6),
  Pneumonia2 = c(17.4,19,17,18.4,18.2)
  )

combi <- as.matrix(combine)

barplot(combi, main="Top 5 hospitals in California", 
    ylab="Mortality/Admission Rates", col = heat.colors(5), las=1, beside = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: If i had to add the legend is it possible to reduce the space between the legend icon and the text?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue earlier (different dataset, tho) and resolved it by using as.numeric() on my dataframe *after* I converted it to matrix with `as.matrix()`. Leaving as `as.numeric()"` out leads to `"Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator"`

¯\*(ツ)*/¯

My df called tmp:

```
> tmp
          125  1245 1252 1254 1525 1545 12125 12425 12525 12545 125245 125425
Freq.x.2d "14" " 1" " 1" " 1" " 3" " 2" " 1"  " 1"  " 9"  " 4"  " 1"   " 5"
Freq.x.3d "13" " 0" " 1" " 0" " 4" " 0" " 0"  " 0"  "14"  " 4"  " 1"   " 2"
> dim(tmp)
[1]  2 28
> is(tmp)
[1] "matrix"    "array"     "structure" "vector"
```

```
> tmp <- as.matrix(tmp)
> dim(tmp)
[1]  2 28
> is(tmp)
[1] "matrix"    "array"     "structure" "vector"
```

```
> tmp <- as.numeric(tmp)
> dim(tmp)
NULL
> is(tmp)
[1] "numeric" "vector"
```

```
barplot(tmp, las=2, beside=TRUE, col=c("grey40","grey80"))
```